# Reading the number printed on the HID iClass card

Tags: smartcard, uniqueidentifier, serial-number, winscard, common-access-card

I want to read the number printed on the HID iClass(2ks) card. Using WinScard.dll i was able to read the UID and ATR.

I had done some research and came to a conclusion that the printed number is a programmed data and might be protected by a PIN. Am I correct here? If so, how do I read this printed number.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For (dumb) memory cards (and from the 2k I assume that it is one with 2 kByte) typically reading is always possible and just for writing the PIN must have been verified. The default PIN typically preset is 0000.