# HID iClass dl smart card how to get card number

Tags: python, smartcard, wiegand

I'm using the HID omnikey 5022 card reader
The card has HID iClass DL written on it.
Facility code is 147
Card number is 4511

using PySmartCard I can read the
ATR = 3B8F8001804F0CA0000003060A0018000000007A
UID = 7BA49412FEFF12E0
Using a smart card reader application it tells me the card is type iClass 2ks
I also pretty sure it has a weigand 26 bit code.

I've followed every guide I can find on the internet on how to parse this in to card number and get nonsense results.
The common method seems to be,
1, convert ATR to binary
11101110001111100000000000000110000000010011110000110010100000000000000000000000000011000001100000101000000000
2, get rid of LSB (far right digit)
3, get next 16 digits from right and this should be Card number
0000010100000000 = 128 ?? This should be 4511
4, the next 8 from right should be the facility code.
10000011 =131 ?? This should be 147

I'm probably doing something silly here as it looks like it should be pretty straight forwards.  Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24139766/1435475).

Answer (score 0):

I don't share the expectation, that the numbers you know have to appear somewhere in the UID or ATR.

The main purpose of the ATR is establishing communication, so there are only the "historical bytes" available for arbitrary content, which in your case are the 15 bytes preceding the final byte (which is the checksum of the ATR).

The UID is from the chip manufacturer and is unlikely to be relevant.

So the reasonable place to put in something concerning the physical access application you apparently encountered is obviously the standard memory of the card. This is protected by diversified 64 bit key encryption and so may not be recognizable on the fly.

Comment: Thanks guidot.  Just shows how much I know about these. The reading I’d done suggested it would be in the ATR but maybe that’s for a different type of card? I’ll have to try and find a way of reading the memory to see if that makes any sense…. The other question you linked to is indeed closely related thanks..  any idea how I get this data ?